# It possible to convert java source file to a .exe file?

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, jar-signing

I have tested followed by this : Created the jar file and "right click" it, one new window opened than click "properties " menu than click the"change" button  to choose the program you want to use to open this file as  java installed directory path and double click it,run correctly.

1.Any other than this way to convert Java source file as(*.java) or a class file (*.class),need to use any third party jar file?

2. how can I convert it to a .exe file?

Thanks in advance for your reply...!

Comment: You need a 3PP for conversion of .jar file to .class file. This link may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272107/how-can-i-convert-a-jar-file-to-an-exe-file

Comment: You can certainly do this and you've been given some links that should help bit be aware that you're converting a jar which can run on any system **that has java installed** to one which can only be run on a specific system (e.g windows) even if it doesn't have java installed. This is a legitimate thing to do but make sure it's what you want to do. Your question suggests what you may want a runnable jar which is something slightly different

Answer (score 0):

You can use exe4j to package all java jars into one  .exe , which can use as normal windows application.