# Custom icon for custom file in Java

Tags: java, windows

I am coding a windows program in Java (something likes sticker on screen for writing some important notes, etc). Automatically, it saves and encodes everything you type in when it's closed. For save I made custom file extension (.T22) but it shows as blank page. I want to change that automatically when program is first started. Basically I want custom icon for save files likes for example photoshop has for its .psd files, but all made in java.

I tried looking through a lot of sites but I couldn't find anyone even talking about it.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be achieved from Java. Well, at least without administrator rights. Windows show icons for file extensions by taking values from [Windows Registries.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry) The thing is that, when an icon takes place, it must take for all users according to [this link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/how-to-assign-a-custom-icon-to-a-file-type) In the link, `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`  is referred in order to achieve that. That's where the "administrator rights" part come. It's worth to mention, without being 100% sure, that a .JAR file (a java application) can be executed with admin rights, only if you execute `cmd` *as administrator* and then `java -jar myapp.jar`. I had spend a lot of hours one day in order to edit these registries from Java and i did not manage to do it without administrator rights. (If you do it, let me know how you did :) )

Now, assume you have admin rights, one way, would be a simple 
`reg` command from admin privileged `cmd`.

As described in the previous link though, you cannot simple (i am not so sure) change the icon for a file extension, without giving the full path of your program's executable (`.exe`). Yes, you guessed it right, your program, is not a windows executable. It is just a compressed file. So, this gets rejected as well.

Now, your problem heads right to [How can I convert a JAR file to an EXE file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272107/how-can-i-convert-a-jar-file-to-an-exe-file). Then, plus the admin rights, you might be able to do it.

My personal advice though, is to find a JAR to EXE converter which gives this option during program installation. I mean, i am sure you have seen in a windows installation something like "Associate .txt files with Notepad ++".

Comment: After some time tinkering I managed to do this: 1. convert JAR to EXE 2. create .bat file that sets default app for opening the .t22 file as my program 3. created installation in inno setup that runs the batch file after installation. Downside: as I was just now introduced to inno setup I don't know how to make the .bat file with installation so the installation folder can be anywhere ... therefor I made it that the user can't change installation folder.